# How can it be verified that ClamAV is detecting a particular malware?

Tags: malware, anti-virus, clamav

I have ClamAV running and updating via Freshclam. How can it be determined if ClamAV's current signatures in `daily.cvd` are indeed detecting a particular malware item?

A very similar question was found on the ClamAV Users list: [how to verify if a malware signature is in DB & adding hash](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-users/2019-May/007990.html) but the discussion ran out of steam with an answer that amounts to "trust us".

In the same thread, the project lead, Joel Esler says *"subscribe to the clamav-virusdb list"*. The [clamav-virusdb list archives](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/) unfortunately scrub all attachments, so there's no way to see what work was done. If it weren't scrubbed, that information is precisely what I'm looking for; and so my question remains open.

Comment: The file that updates the AV should have a version for that date. The software maker should have a list of current versions you could use.

Comment: malware is coded and released into the wild every day, all signatures are at least 2 weeks behind the latest malware. Some are so stealthy they never get detected by AV once they are on the PC. AV just doesn't work anymore but is better than nothing i suppose.

Comment: @John "The file that updates the AV" is `daily.cvd`. Yes, I'm not looking for a _date_ but something that assures me that one malware in particular is being detected by the `daily.cvd` that I have.

Comment: @Moab That's an interesting observation and a possible different angle on what I'm asking. How would I verify that 2 week lead time?

Comment: Its an statement made by most all security experts, they advise anything you download should be kept in a folder for 2 weeks at least, then scan for malware, if they come up clean it is relatively safe to use the file. I don't use AV, its a waste of time and PC resources, I just very careful what I download and what web pages I visit.

Comment: If i'm suspicious about a file I upload it to VirusTotal for analysis, but 2 weeks rule still applies.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a piece of malware, and you want to ensure that a scan of certain antivirus is able to detect it, the is to scan the malware file and verify that it is correctly detected.

Second option would be to scan it with an online scanner (such as VirusTotal), although that might not be completely accurate if -for some reason- your local install is not detecting it (it could be configured differently, have outdated signatures, etc).

This assumes that you actually know the malware file you are looking for. For example, after getting PC003 infected, you discovers that an updated ClamAV finds all and then want to scan all of the company machines / server shares for that exact piece.

For ClamAV, you could even add a signature yourself with the hash of the sought file, if not detected by public signatures.

Please note that this approach may not completely work if it is a polymorphic malware (i.e. the dropped files are different on every machine, so detection of one instance is encouraging, but doesn't guarantee detection of the rest).

Not so much applicable to ClamAV, but there are also cases where the AV won't directly detect malware on a file scan, but it would heuristically block it *when executed*, based on its behavior, so you might be actually a bit safer than what this scan provides.

Finally, an important restriction is that you do need to know the particular malware item you are interested in. If what you know is not a file hash, but a malware name, most likely it is actually a malware *family*, with up to thousands of samples. Hopefully, an AV would be able to detect most of them with a few signatures, but (a) signatures detecting a strain doesn't mean it detects all of them (as they will be changing continuously, it may need new signatures every few days/months) and (b) no specific signature doesn't mean it won't detect them, either, as it could be caught by a signature with a generic name.

---

**Edit:** showing the above with a real example, as it seems from the comments that it is still not clear. Rich mentions knowing if the AV detectss Sodinokibi.

I searched [Sodinokibi in VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/search/sodinokibi/comments) and picked the most recent example shown, which happens to be  [8f57dd9eb80974e98bf64a19999db50f](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/63427bee1d18f5eb9f76a29ae2087ef4fe876480d5998a4d75397bee7f9f82bc/detection)

This shows the multiple names of the signature names I mentioned:

- Trojan[Ransom]/Win32.Gen (Antiy-AVL)
- Win32:Trojan-gen (AVG)
- DeepScan:Generic.Ransom.Sodinokibi.DC94C06B (BitDefender)
- W32.AIDetectVM.malware2 (Bkav)
- Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-7013612-0 (ClamAV)
- Trojan.Encoder.30497 (DrWeb)
- W32/Sodinokibi.B!tr.ransom (Fortinet)
- Ransom.Sodinokibi (Malwarebytes)
- W32/Kryptik.AKW.gen!Eldorado (Cyren)
- HEUR:Trojan-Ransom.Win32.Gen.gen (Kaspersky)
- Sodinokibi!8F57DD9EB809 (McAfee)
  and many, many more

Some clearly name the intended target of the signature as Sodinokibi. Others are generic, or even unclear. And for example, "Trojan.Encoder.30497" is a very clearly named. But it is using a specific naming by the vendor. You need to know that Dr.Web names the ransomware as "Trojan.Encoder", and that .30497 is Sodinokibi.

Ok, but this question is about ClamAV, and it *is* using a clearly named signature (Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-7013612-0). If you have a signature naming the threat, all is good, right?

Well, I installed ClamAV (0.102.4) and ran freshclam to download the most recent signatures (26 Aug 2020 09-18 -0400:25911).

We can view the signatures using `sigtool --list-sigs`. grepping the word Sodinokibi finds two signatures on daily.cvd: Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-6966152-0 and Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-6996917-1 (no, 7013612-0 is *not* there. Perhaps it would be added on tomorrow's daily?)

So, you have a threat (Sodinokibi), and want to know if you are properly protected from it. Your AV has signatures for Sodinokibi. A VirusTotal scan shows that the AV *detects* the threat. Yet, you do not have the signatures in found in the cloud. Would you consider yourself to be protected, or not?

The only way to really know would be to grab the sample and actually scan it.

And in case you are wondering, after scanning it locally, it does detect it as `Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-7013612-0` even though such signature was not in sigtool list.

Note: Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-7013612-0 was added on [July 11, 2019](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/2019-July/006891.html)

Comment: This is specifically the situation I do not want to get into where I have to provide the infected file as a sample. I want to check the vendor's signature database to ensure the malware is accounted for.

Comment: I tried to address that, @Rich. You can't win. Unless you have a binary for the malware you want to check if it is detected, you can't know. Some vendors will detect it as Win.Trojan-123456. Others will detect it as generic.malware, others will detect is as something else, or use a signature from an earlier variant, yet other vendor could have a signature whose name appears to mean that it detects it, yet it is missed.

Comment: For showing a real example, do you have an example of a malware you would want to ensure is accounted for?

Comment: Let's use the examples from the mailing list - _Sodinokibi_ and _Muhstik_. It's reasonable to look these up in a generic database. I'm not talking about "some vendors" though, just one.

Comment: Googling the first lands us at https://bazaar.abuse.ch/browse.php?search=Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi-7013612-0&type=clamav which nicely exposes the sig name in the URI (but nowhere else) - `Win.Ransomware.Sodinokibi`

Comment: That can be trimmed to a google query `site:bazaar.abuse.ch sodinokibi` - the pattern of which doesn't turn up results for the second name "Muhstik" or some other recents. It's a vast improvement over the initial position of not being able to find any list anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: @Rich: see the edit

Comment: Wow. After all this time `sigtool` was hiding in plain sight. (And I'm baffled why the lead maintainer didn't draw attention to this in that thread.)

Answer (score 0):

### Subscribe to the `clamav-virusdb` list

The ClamAV project lead, Joel Esler advises in [a thread on the `clamav-users` list](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-users/2019-May/007991.html) to [*"subscribe to the clamav-virusdb list"*](https://lists.clamav.net/mailman/listinfo/clamav-virusdb).

The [clamav-virusdb list archives](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/) unfortunately include this information as attached text files all named `attachment.ksh`; which makes searching them a pain. The search could be automated with a few choice `curl`s concatenated into a single file to `grep` into.

This is a start:

```
for x in \
$(curl https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/2020-August/thread.html \
|sed -n '/Published/s/.*HREF=.//p'|sed 's/".*//'); do
    curl https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/2020-August/$x|grep URL:
done
```

I tested this by using `wget` on the returned attachment URLs to pull them into a local directory. Sure, you could mirror with `wget` but I want control over dates. I was then able to `grep` across the files for a couple of signature names which confirmed their presence in the Clam signatures.

Thanks to @Ángel for the clue that got me there.

Comment: Not really, the list is converting the email content into an attachment (so you need another click), but the information is there. For instance, [last mail](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/2020-August/007297.html) and [its contents](https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-virusdb/attachments/20200825/4282c30b/attachment.ksh)

Comment: @Ángel Wow, that's really surprising. You can see why I was reluctant to download a file ending in `.ksh` to a Unix box... Thank you for the detail, I've amended my answer to suit.